# Is there any difference to use group by in a query ?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a query

```
SELECT bk_publisher, bk_price FROM books
GROUP BY bk_price, bk_publisher
```

and

```
SELECT bk_publisher ,bk_price FROM books
```

both are returning the same results. Means i have 12 records in my table and both queries returning the 12 records. What is the difference ? Although i am using group by, which is use with aggregate functions. But i want to know is group by making any difference here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT bk_publisher, bk_price FROM books
GROUP BY bk_price, bk_publisher
```

Will result distinct pairs of (publisher, price), even if your table  contains duplicated data.

Comment: What do you mean by `distinct pairs of (publisher, price)`? I have duplicate records for bk_publisher. If i use `SELECT
bk_publisher AS publisher
, SUM(bk_price) AS books_total
FROM books
GROUP BY bk_publisher`. Then i understand that i have four duplicate records, which combine to one by using group by.

Comment: you will have one record for every pair (publisher, price). So you can have duplicates on publisher but with different price they all will be returned.

Comment: Yes i have duplicates but prices are different. You mean if i make two records same, like i have four records `bk_publisher = wiley` with different price. If i make two wiley records prices same then group by only show distinct records, means no duplicate ? is it ? while without group by query shows all the records. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant :)

Comment: hhhmm means like here i am using `GROUP BY bk_price, bk_publisher`. So it is kind of saying that make a group of bk_price and bk_publisher and then show the distinct records. If i only use `GROUP BY bk_price` then it means make a group of only `bk_price` and then show distinct records... Ok got it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) helps you group different results by some identical value (using aggregation functions on other values)

In your case it doesn't mean anything, but when you want to aggregate values based on identical field, you use group by.

For example, if you want to get the max price of a publisher:

```
SELECT bk_publisher, max(bk_price) FROM books
GROUP BY bk_publisher
```

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY statement is used to group the result-set by one or more columns.Group by is used when you have repeating data and you want single record for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `GROUP BY`, it will squeeze multiple rows having identical columns listed in `GROUP BY` as single row in output.

It also means that in general, all other columns mentioned in `SELECT` list must be wrapped in aggregate functions like `sum()`, `avg()`, `count()`, etc.

Some SQL engines like MySQL permit not using aggregates, but many people consider this a bug.

Answer (score 0):

**GROUP BY** clause is apparently showing no effect because there is no repeating combination of `bk_price, bk_publisher` values.